# Are there special characters that can be used for sorting but not displaying?

Tags: sorting, special-characters, list, whitespace, ordering

We have a short simple list of text strings on a platform that forces alphabetical order. We'd like to have a custom order without prefixing numbers or other distracting characters (it's a customer-facing menu).

Example:

- Investigate
- Order
- Sell

  ↓↓↓ (Add some invisible prefixes to achieve desired order)
- Investigate
- Sell
- Order

Could we prefix each string with some kind of special characters (Unicode?) which either won't display at all (but contribute to the ordering) or else display as space of same width (so the menu items still look aligned)?

Any other suggestions?

EDIT 2022-08-02: Although I accepted Máté Juhász' answer, below are some other types of characters I found.
NOTE 1: On Windows, the UNICODE can be used as an [Alt+Plus code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code#Transition_to_Unicode).
NOTE 2: Since these characters are invisible, I put each symbol between 'll', to make it easier to see how wide they are (their width can be different on different platforms, so first copy these to your destination to compare them).

**CHARACTERS OF SIMILAR WIDTH TO A REGULAR SPACE**:

```
UNICODE SYMBOL  DESCRIPTION  
0020    l l     SPACE - size: 1/4 em (f)  
202F    l l     NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE  
00A0    l l     NO-BREAK SPACE - size: 1/4 em  
2005    l l     FOUR-PER-EM SPACE (mid space) - size: 1/4 em  
200A    l  l        HAIR SPACE (need 2 of these)  
205F    l l     MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE - size: 2/9 em  
2009    l l     THIN SPACE
```

**ZERO-WIDTH CHARACTERS** (careful, some may affect your text):

```
UNICODE SYMBOL  DESCRIPTION  
2028    l l     Line separator  
180E    l᠎l     Zero width mongolian vowel separator  
200B    l​l     Zero width space  
2029    l l     Paragraph separator, careful  
0085    ll      Next line (nel), careful  
200C    l‌l     Zero width non-joiner  
FEFF    ll      Zero width no-break space  
2060    l⁠l     Word joiner  
200D    l‍l     Zero width joiner
```

**MISCELLANEOUS SIZED INVISIBLE CHARACTERS**:

```
UNICODE SYMBOL  DESCRIPTION  
3000    l　l     Ideographic space  
2002    l l     En space  
2000    l l     En quad  
2001    l l     Em quad  
2003    l l     Em space  
2004    l l     Three-per-em space  
2006    l l     Six-per-em space
```

Comment: "on a platform"… what platform? On macOS you can prefix with spaces, which is technically 'visible' but minimally distracting.

Comment: Are you sure your edit belongs to the question? In case it doesn't: [*Can I answer my own question?*](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, I just wanted to give Máté the credit for a valid answer. So I simply provided extra information for an alternative solution. I would have written it in a comment to Máté, so everyone can see it, but comments have a character limit and don't support copyable tabulated data (afaik). But I don't know what I'm doing, so if you order me to create a separate answer, I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use [zero - width space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)

It has larger code than letters, so text without that is the first, text preceded by one is the second, text preceded by two zero-width space is the third and so on.

Comment: Can that be used in all of the filesystems of the "big 3" OSs?

Comment: @Albin the question is not about objects in file system but items of a list in a tool.

Comment: doh...  I'm ashamed now... I was reading the comment "mac os" and thought of a file system...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about any "blank" special characters, but I have "another" suggestion: I like to use symbols especially `_`, others in particular`+ # @` and `z` possibliy "stacked" like `_`, `__`, `___` etc. or in combination with numbers e.g. `_1` (but you don't want numbers).

Expanding on Tetsujin's comment:
If you can not use spaces at the beginning of the file/folder (eg in Windows), you can use a symbol `_` in front, eg. `_ filename` (one space), `_  filename` (two spaces) etc.

Comment: To force certain files to the end of the sort, I've used NBSP (non-breaking space), ASCII(160), i.e.,  Space (32) + 128 (high bit)./

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, are there region specific settings at work here?

Comment: Sometimes the filename must be changed from terminal (CMD). NBSP is not Unicode, and should be valid on all systems except EBCDIC and TTY.